# crear app en Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, web

Soy nuevo por aquí, no he podido dejar pasar la oportunidad de echar mano a un recurso tan magnánimo como este.

Mi primera pesquisa rota en torno a node.js

¿cómo crear una app partiendo de un simple script como el que acompaño de ejemplo?

```js
var de = Math.random()*(100-1)+1;
        var de2 = Math.random()*(100-1)+1;
        var de3 = de * de2

        if (de <=50) {
            alert("menor")

        } else  {
            alert("mayor");
            
        }
```

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Lo primero que se menciona es que este sitio _no es un foro de discusión_. Aquí no se dan tutoriales ni orientaciones. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). En este sitio se responden a preguntas _específicas_.

Comment: Entendido. Lo lamento. Voy a editarlo para que quede en la forma conminada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con un simple `npm init` en una terminal puedes crear un proyecto vacio, entonces a ese nuevo proyecto puedes instalarle librerias o agregarle codigo propio.
[Te dejo una guia](https://lenguajejs.com/npm/administracion/crear-nuevo-proyecto/)

Comment: Gracias! ese enlace es justo lo que buscaba para orientarme

Comment: De nada, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada. ❤️

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que pruebes haciendo un servidor usando express con node.
Mediante este modulo puedes hacer peticiones http al servidor y por ejemplo pasarle datos en la ruta, etc.
Además este es sencillo de usar y tienes muchísimas guías.
Y con respecto a usar ese script puedes hacer por ejemplo una webpage que lo  devuelva:

```
localhost:3000/math
```

Te adjunto la información necesaria para instalar y usar el modulo express, así como su documentación.
[Resumen general de Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

Comment: Ya lo utilicé en un tutorial. Gracias por el link